# Vue3 + Vite. How to transpile dependencies?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a Vue 3 project that uses Vite.

[NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jsonforms/vue-vanilla) that I want to use requires me to modify vue.config.js and do the following:

```
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ['@jsonforms/core', '@jsonforms/vue2', '@jsonforms/vue2-vanilla']
}
```

However, Vite projects don't use vue.config.js, instead they have vite.config.js (I assume they are not equivalent in what they do).

How do I configure such NPM package to work in Vite based Vue projects?